# update on duplicate key with JdbcBatchItemWriter

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-batch, insert-update

spring Batch for my project, and I'm simply trying to read from a csv file and load data to a database, using JdbcBatchItemWriter as writer.

I'm looking for a way to tell the writer to insert a new row, but, on duplicate key (or duplicate unique identifier)  update row instead of failing.

I know I can do that directly in the sql statement, but that would be specific to Mysql, though I want my code to be DBMS-independent.

here is my writer declaration in the java config

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemWriter<Person> writerHeadingCollectionsToDb(DataSource datasource) {

    String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO abcd(id, first_name, last_name, phone_number"
            + "VALUES (:id, :firstName, :lastName, :phoneNumber)";


    JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person>();
    itemWriter.setSql(sqlStatement );
    itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Person>());
    return itemWriter;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy:
Write a custom `ItemWriter<>` and in `write()` method do an insert and - if duplication - do an update; to check if dup key use a lookup or a duplicate exception catch.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Bellabax. That was a interesting way of doing. However, As I'm using MySql as DBMS, and I know I wont use anything else in this project, I finally did it on the SQL side. I just added 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...' at the end of my query.